# Viewpager Inside Recyclerview As Item Prevent Scroll of Recyclerview using Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a `ViewPager` as a Item in my `RecyclerView`.
`Viewpager` scroll horizontally is working fine but when I am trying to scroll vertically my `RecyclerView` by picking my `ViewPager` which is item of `RecyclerView`; my `RecyclerView` is not scrolling.

```
 mRecyclerViewCarouselInfo.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
 mRecyclerViewCarouselInfo.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            int action = e.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent event) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    });
```

My layout code for Recyclerview is as below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_gap_8">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector_bg"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: To me this code itself, is working with ViewPager2 in a ViewHolder in RecyclerView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
mRecyclerViewCarouselInfo.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.